# Query database with dot in its name

Tags: sql-server, excel, odbc

We have a database that has a "." in it name.  We need to be able to query this database from excel and excel is not having it.  I've tried to put [] around the name, but excel just ignores the brackets.  Attached is a picture of the query I'm trying to run.  I've tried setting up different ODBC connections, but excel just sees the dot and assumes everything before the dot is the name of the database.

[image: Picture]

I have no idea why the vendor named the database this, but they will not change it.

Comment: Wait, the name of the database is `C:\database.mdf`? That's not just a path to the `.mdf` file?

Comment: I suspect that the application is just attaching that mdf file as opposed to that actually being the database name. My guess is the database name is "database".

Comment: Well it is both.  They named the database the path to the .mdf file.  The vendor has no idea what is going on, but regardless yes that is the name of the database.

Comment: Well can't you just establish the connection to that horribly named database? Then you don't need to specify the database name in your query.

Comment: What do you mean establish a connection?